# Quicker deepcopy in Python; large list is 15x slower to deepcopy vs copy

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, copy

I have a script to demonstrate:

```py
#!/usr/bin/env python3

import time
import copy

def reset():
    a = [[{'1': [5, 2, 6, 7, 9], '2': 6, '3': 5}], [{'1': [5, 2, 6, 7, 9], '2': 6, '3': 5}]]
    b = []
    return a, b

a, b = reset()

start = time.time()
b = list(a)
end = time.time()
print("list(a) took:", end-start)
a[0][0]['1'] = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
print("b changed with a" if b == a else "b did not change with a")
a, b = reset()

start = time.time()
b = a[:]
end = time.time()
print("a[:] took:", end-start)
a[0][0]['1'] = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
print("b changed with a" if b == a else "b did not change with a")
a, b = reset()

start = time.time()
b = copy.copy(a)
end = time.time()
print("copy(a) took:", end-start)
a[0][0]['1'] = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
print("b changed with a" if b == a else "b did not change with a")
a, b = reset()

start = time.time()
b = copy.deepcopy(a)
end = time.time()
print("deepcopy(a) took:", end-start)
a[0][0]['1'] = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
print("b changed with a" if b == a else "b did not change with a")
```

And an output:

```
list(a) took: 1.1920928955078125e-06
b changed with a
a[:] took: 7.152557373046875e-07
b changed with a
copy(a) took: 3.337860107421875e-06
b changed with a
deepcopy(a) took: 2.5510787963867188e-05
b did not change with a
```

Is there no faster way to deepcopy? I am passing a list to a function which is then mutated. I want to keep a copy of the list before it was changed to compare the two but `deepcopy` is way too slow. I am talking a typically 1s execution vs 15s.

An example of my data is below:

```
[[{'w': [0.5372377247650572, 1.9111341091016385, -3.2165806256024116, -1.7154987465370053, 1.0917999534858416], 'o': 0.0004326739879156587, 'd': 3.586499431857422e-05}],[{'w': [7.298542669399767, -3.9021024252822105], 'o': 0.019860841402923542, 'd': 0.00105997759946847}, {'w': [-2.8024625186056764, -0.34819658506990847], 'o': 0.4135257109795849, 'd': -0.0016469874583619935}, {'w': [-6.018257518762189, 0.3317488378886934], 'o': 0.5815513019444986, 'd': -1.1787471334339458e-05}]]
```

Comment: First, doing a single measurement is not as accurate as you might think; try the `timeit` facility instead.  Second, why are you comparing `copy` with `deepcopy`?  They don't do the same job.  The difference in speed is going to depend on the depth of your data structure.

Comment: You're facing an inherent problem in the task: copying the entire heterogeneous structure, complete with references.  This is not a simple block move.

Comment: Sometimes restructuring data can help. For instance, if there are a bunch of dicts with the same key/value layout, converting to a list and using indexes can speed things up. If the data can live comfortably in a `numpy` array or `pandas` dataframe, you get another speedup still. This may not apply in your case, of course.

Comment: @tdelaney I'm not sure how I could convert it to a pandas dataframe, considering the length of dicts may be different.

Comment: @gator Can you share what your actual data looks like?

Comment: @gator Python copy.deepcopy() constructs a new compound object and then, recursively, inserts copies into it of the objects found in the original. So, basically it copies everything that is found in a class object multiple levels deep. But, copy.copy() can be thought of as copy.deepcopy() for just one level of class members. Therefore, it is expected that deepcopy() will perform more or less worse  than copy() since the operation overhead is always higher.

Comment: @AMC Sure. I've added it to the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're only aiming to detect changes, instead of making a copy, you could try to only store a hash of the structure and check if the new hash is different:

```
d = [[{'1': [5, 2, 6, 7, 9], '2': 6, '3': 5}], [{'1': [5, 2, 6, 7, 9], '2': 6, '3': 5}]]

def hashIt(d):
    if isinstance(d,list):
        return hash(tuple(hashIt(i) for i in d))
    if isinstance(d,dict):
        return hash(tuple(((k,hashIt(v))) for k,v in d.items()))
    return hash(d)


hashBefore = hashIt(d)

d[1][0]["1"][2]=11

print(hashBefore == hashIt(d)) # false

d[1][0]["1"][2]=6

print(hashBefore == hashIt(d)) # true
```

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know, there isn't a faster way to copy an object instance in python if you want recursive copying of objects across multiple levels. Python `copy.deepcopy()` constructs a new compound object and then, recursively, inserts copies into it of the objects found in the original. So, basically it copies everything that is found in a class object multiple levels deep. But, copy.copy() can be thought of as `copy.deepcopy()` for just one level of class members. Therefore, it is expected that `deepcopy()` will perform more or less worse than `copy()` since the operation overhead is always higher. The following snippet might help you understand

```
import copy

def printer(objs):
    for obj in objs:
        for key, val in sorted(obj.items()):
            print(key+':',val,end=' ')
        print()

x = [{'a':[1,2,3], 'b':[4,5,6], 'c':[7,8,9]},
     {'d':[1,2,3], 'e':[4,5,6], 'f':[7,8,9]},
     {'g':[1,2,3], 'h':[4,5,6], 'i':[7,8,9]}]
y, z = copy.copy(x), copy.deepcopy(x)

x[0]['a'][1] = 0
x[1]['e'][1] = 0
x[2]['i'][1] = 0

printer(x)
print()
printer(y)
print()
printer(z)
```